# Do something when local notification is presented when app is terminated or in the background

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, unusernotificationcenter, unnotificationtrigger

I know there's the will present method that will be called only when the app is in foreground state. Now I want the app to do something if the user ignored the notification. In this case I want present another view controller during the next launch (when notification is ignored). I want the will present method to be called when app is in the background or app is terminated. Any help will be appreciated